# Query on Designing Object Structure

Tags: java, object

I need to convert my customized objects to native Java Object. My Object structure is

```
Map (String, List<MyObject>)
```

I am planning to convert this to

```
Map (String, List <Map <1, Map <MyObject.PropertyName, MyObject.PropertyValue> > >)
```

Is this the optimal way of doing it? Is there any other efficient way?

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: any specific reason for not using your own object definition?

Comment: I am not sure about efficiency; but former one is more sane. Plus, you'll loose IDE support and any misspelling in property name will return you Null as it's value.

Comment: I need to use it across different application servers. So I can't use my own object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following?

```
Map<String,Properties> yourMap = new HashMap<String,Properties>();
```

I think that what you describe fits the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

Comment: You mean `java.util.Properties`?